# Yii 2 installation

Tags: yii, installation, yii2

it is easy to install Yii 1.x using cmd and yiic webapp command.but for yii-2 will it work?i found that yiic command is not recognzied as internal or external so kindly suggest any similar method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two type of installation with Yii2

1. Using Composer

> composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic

2. Using Archive zip

> http://www.yiiframework.com/download/

Both Installation are similar but the main difference is that when using composer you automatically create a cookieValidationKey. On the other hand using an archive zip you unzip and edit config/web.php to set your cookieValidationKey.

As for the yiic command it was removed and what we have now is ./yii
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html

Answer (score 1):

It really is all here in easy to follow instructions 
[Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html)